# Strings; substrings. Not understanding a block of codes

Tags: c++, string

This is a program that creates a username for a user who enters their first name and last name.

Username = user's first initial + up to 7 letters of user's last name.

Ex: John Smith becomes 'jsmith'

John Smoother becomes 'jsmoothe'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fullname, fname, lname, uname, u2;
    int l, len;

    cout<<"FULLNAME: ";
    getline(cin, fullname);

    l=fullname.length();
    cout<<"Fullname length: "<<l<<endl;

/*
len=0;
    while (len!=(l-1))
    {
        if (fullname[len]!=' ')
            len++;
        else
            break;
    }

    fname=fullname.substr(0,len);
    lname=fullname.substr(len+1, (l-len));
*/

    cout<<"FName: "<<fname<<endl;
    cout<<"LName: "<<lname<<endl;

    if(isupper(fname[0]))
    {
        fname[0]=fname[0] + 32;
    }
    if(isupper(lname[0]))
{
    lname[0]=lname[0] + 32;

    }

    cout<<"FName: "<<fname<<endl;
    cout<<"LName: "<<lname<<endl;

    uname=fname.substr(0,1);
    u2=lname.substr(0,7);

    uname+=u2;
    cout<<"USERNAME: "<<uname;

    return 0;
}
```

I am having difficulties understand the block of codes i put between comments (*/.../*).

Comment: This loop advances the `len` variable to the next index of a `' '` character.

Comment: separate name from last name , ( the while is looking for the ' ' character)

Comment: It counts the characters in `fullname` to the first `' '` because after this is done it wants to put first part of `fullname` in `fname` and the rest in `lname`.

Comment: @Daimonz you should choose a line in code that you don't understand and give the question specific title, i.e: "string substr"

Answer (score 0):

It is a silly code so do not try to understand it. It would have been much better if you had wrote the code by yourself. In this case, you would not ask such a question.

The author of the code tries to count first non-space characters and then to extract them using method `substr` and to place them in `fname`. Remaining characters are placed in `lname`.

Take into account that the code is invalid. For example the entered string can start with blanks. Also between the two names there can be more than one blank.
Also, it would have been much better if it was written for example

```
fname[0] = tolower( fname[0] );
```

instead of

```
fname[0]=fname[0] + 32;
```

And I think you need to convert all the characters of names to lower case.

Comment: Im revising my lectures and i came across this.  So i had to understand it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yes...i checked that...not the best username creator i agree.

Comment: Also, the author could use `std::string::find` and `find_first_not_of` for determining where the start and end of words are.

Answer (score -2):

It is simple ,if your string is "John Hoffman",len will equal to 4